# Dictionary of Hyphenated Words in English

Tags: compiling, hyphenation, documentation

In reading about TeX's [hyphenation algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398491/how-does-texs-hyphenation-algorithm-work), I found the [tex-hyphen repo](https://github.com/hyphenation/tex-hyphen/blob/master/hyph-utf8/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-en-us.tex) with a bunch of patterns listed (over 4,000 in that file). The answer on the hyphenation algorithm suggested that they compile and generate these patterns from existing dictionaries from publishers. I imagine these to be, rather than TeX hyphenation patterns, individual hyphenation examples such as `exa-mple` for "example" or whatever. How the hyphenation points are determined I have no idea, seems like it is on a per-word basis without a clear science (hence the patterns).

So I wanted to see if there exists these dictionaries of the hyphenation *examples* (as opposed to the hyphenation *patterns*). Wondering if one could list some resources where they may be found, or if none then knowing they are private or whatever would be helpful.

Comment: [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line) suggests that hyphenation examples should be a common feature of ordinary dictionaries. Indeed, consider the [second line here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/example). I can't tell whether ex·am·ple is the hyphenation pattern, the syllable pattern, or if there is even much of a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UK English ones were made available at the time by Oxford University press just for making the tex patterns and not generally available, The US English ones were produced using the hyphenation of Webster's
Pocket Dictionary (Merriam, 1966) as referenced in the texbook

Comment: :See also this answer to a previous question on this subject: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171155  It contains an actual example from the purported source of the UK hyphenation patterns.